# Predict next value in sequence R

Tags: r, sequence, predict, forecast

I am looking for a model to predict the next value of the sequences below. The original data is:

```
structure(list(job1category = c(5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 
5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), job2category = c(5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 5, 
1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 
5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), job3category = c(5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 
5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 
1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), job4category = c(5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 
2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I explored the most frequent pairs of digits after joinung the values of the 4 columns into one string and found 5 5 to be number one.

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("5 5", "1 1", 
"1 5", "3 3", "2 2"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(125L, 104L, 
21L, 18L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Now I want to predict the next value after a 5 5 occurred. Therefore, I found all sequences that have a 5 5 anywhere in the sequence and only look at everything after the first 5:

```
Freq_Top1 <- 
structure(list(data_rel1 = c("5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", 
"1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", 
"1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "2 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", 
"1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "3 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", 
"5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "4 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", 
"3 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", 
"5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", 
"1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", 
"1 5 5 5", "1 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5", "5 5 5 5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried with the PSF library but the following code gives me an error. Do I have to preprocess the data more? Or is there a better way to predict the next value?

```
nottem_model <- psf(Freq_Top1)
Error in data - dmin : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The outcome of the prediction will obviously state the value 5 because of the unbalanced data that I am feeding the model but I am still looking for a model that can do the prediction. Any tip is appreciated!

Comment: Your data are character strings and they are all equal to the string `"1 5 5 5"`. Are you sure that those are right?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I explained the problem very poorly, please see the updated question!